# How get Doctrine sortable "Duplicate entry error"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with doctrine sortable extension.

first of all, i have a House entity with 1:n Releation to HouseImage entity (setup to save the image postion)
and a HouseImage entity 1:1 releation to File entity.

```
class House
{
    /**
     * @var HouseImage[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="HouseImage",
     *     mappedBy="houses",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
     *     orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $images;

}


/**
 * HouseImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name=house_image)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository")
 */
class HouseImage {


    /**
     * @var House
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="House",
     *     inversedBy="images",
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="house_id",
     *     referencedColumnName="id",
     *     onDelete="SET NULL"
     * )
     * @Gedmo\SortableGroup
     */
    protected $houses;

    /**
     * @var File
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(
     *     targetEntity="File",
     * )
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="image_id",
     *     referencedColumnName="id",
     *     nullable=false,
     * )
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    protected $position;
    
    
    ....
}

//so i create some HouseImage-Objects

$HouseImage = new HouseImage();
$HouseImage->setImage($myFile);

$HouseImage2 = new HouseImage();
$HouseImage2->setImage($myFile2);

$HouseImage3 = new HouseImage();
$HouseImage3->setImage($myFile3);

//add first image-relation to house
$house->setImages([$HouseImage]);
$em->persist($house);
$em->flush();

//add second image-relation, should be inserted at first position 
$house->setImages([$HouseImage2, $HouseImage]);

$em->persist($house);
$em->flush();

//add new list of image-relation 
$house->setImages([$HouseImage2, $HouseImage3]);

$em->persist($house);
$em->flush();
```

///after flush the entitymanager this error occurred

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO house_image (position, house_id, image_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [0, 123, 999]:\n
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '999' for key 'UNIQ_E0C3790C3DA5256D
```

the some error occurred with form factory

```
$data['images'] = [

    [
        'house' => 181,
        'image' => 123
    ],
    [
        'house' => 181,
        'image' => 1234
    ],
    [
        'house' => 181,
        'image' => 12345
    ],
];

$form   = $formFactory->create(HouseType::class, $houseObject);#
$form->submit($data, false);
```

**Question:**
How can i update the HouseImage-postion in the list by add a list of HouseImage
or
How can i cleanup all entites befor insert a complete new list of HouseImage-Releations

**Edit:**
I have fixed my issue by removing the addImage() method an implement this setImage() Method:

```
public function setImages(Collection $images): void
{
    $col = new ArrayCollection();
    $i = 0;
    /* @var $image HouseImage */
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $image->setHouse($this);
        $image->setPosition($i++);

        $col->add($image);
    }
    $this->images = $col;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way to create the house image entities is a little bit wrong, you can define that House entity should cascade persist your HouseImage collection. You should add this in your House entity:

```
class House
{
  function __construct()
  {
    $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  public function addHouseImage(HouseImage $houseImage)
  {
     $this->images->add($houseImage);
     $houseImage->setHouse($this);
  }
}
```

Also rename **$houses** to **$house** in your HouseImage. **You are linking HouseImage to House(not many houses)**. Also don't forget to link HouseImage with File entity. If you want to set the position after the last image on a new image you do that in addHouseImage function or anywhere else in your application. With the above code you code could look like this:

```
$image1 = ...;
$image2 = ...;
$image3 = ...;

$house->addHouseImage($image1);
add2.
add2.

// This will persist all house images along with house.
$em->persist($house);
$em->flush();
```

If I didn't cover something related to your question pleas let me know
Also the exception

> 'INSERT INTO house_image (position, house_id, image_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [0, 123, 999]:\n SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '999' for key 'UNIQ_E0C3790C3DA5256D

tells you that there already is a File with id 999 in relation and you are trying to set 2 HouseImage entities to the same File entity. I can't spot it in your code but I'm almost certain that it happens somewhere in your code.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have edited my original post and find a solution.